# Connecting a client to a server using GKSession

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, gamekit

What is the proper way to connect two apps using `GKSession`, where one acts as a `GKSessionModeClient` and one as a `GKSessionModeServer`?

For the server, does it start listening after `initWithSessionID:displayName:sessionMode:` is called and `available` is set to `YES`?

How do I search for the server with the client? After I initialize a `GKSession` with the same session ID, I'm not sure how to look for the server and connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The client `GKSession` also needs `available` set to `YES` in order to begin searching. The `GKSessionDelegate` will then be called.